# check In App Purchase Auto Renewable Subscription is valid

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase

I am new to IOS. currently working on in app purchase implementation in my newsstand app.i have implemented auto renewable subscription in my newsstand app.how can i check in app purchase auto renewable subscription is valid or not?

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680059/auto-renewable-subscription-in-ios7/45220204#45220204
might help you.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the subscription you need to store the receipt object.  You can use the receipt to determine if the subscription it represents is valid.

I'm using CargoBay (https://github.com/mattt/CargoBay) to help with StoreKit processing.  It has a method:

```
[[CargoBay sharedManager] verifyTransaction:transaction password:nil success:^(NSDictionary *receipt) {
  NSLog(@"Receipt: %@", receipt);
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error %d (%@)", [error code], [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, I have trouble with this problem.
Follow [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html) here, I used this way to check subscription is expired or not.

This is my code in Objective-C.

```
NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:resData options:0 error:&error]; 
// this is response from AppStore
NSDictionary *dictLatestReceiptsInfo = jsonResponse[@"latest_receipt_info"];
long long int expirationDateMs = [[dictLatestReceiptsInfo valueForKeyPath:@"@max.expires_date_ms"] longLongValue];
long long requestDateMs = [jsonResponse[@"receipt"][@"request_date_ms"] longLongValue];
isValidReceipt = [[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 0 && (expirationDateMs > requestDateMs);
```

Hope this help.