# Auto-Renewable Subscription in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

The company I work for has a lot of education apps in the app store (SAT Prep, ACT Prep, GRE Prep, etc...). The current business model is the user downloads the app for free with a handful of sample questions, and is given the option to buy 6 months of access to all the questions, a year, or lifetime.

we want to make the 6 month & 1 year options auto-renewable... is this possible? from what I've read apple really only allows auto-renewable subscriptions on newsstand apps, but we want to try to submit it anyway. Would this be achieved by changing the in app purchase setting in itunes connect from non recurring to recurring? and/or would i have to change the code in some places?

Thanks guys

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680059/auto-renewable-subscription-in-ios7/45220204#45220204
might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking here - [In App Purchase guide lines](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf) + having the same experience I think you might get rejection for using Auto Renewable products in your app. Saying that I think that apple guide lines for product types are not 100% clear, and you can definitely try to submit. I had examples where one reviewer rejected the app claiming for wrong product type but the second approved it with out any changes.

But, if you will get rejected -

1. You will have to create new products, as you can not change product type + if your product list is coded locally on the app you will have to update the list.
2. I am almost sure that auto renewable have a different restore mechanism so you will have to change that too.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This advice will come in handy. I'm in a situation where my boos is asking me for a quote on how much money I would want him to pay me for converting one app and figuring it out. I'm not sure what the process is yet, so I'm trying to figure out what it entails so I can get an idea of how much to charge.