# In app purchase IOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt

I am using in app purchase auto renewable and all working perfect, but my question : is it obligatory to use the receipt of apple or i can generate it by my web service?

So apple would accept my application if I don't use the receipt to validate or not?

Thanks you,

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680059/auto-renewable-subscription-in-ios7/45220204#45220204
might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of receipt validation is to provide security for *you*. How can Apple tell if you are checking receipt validity? Especially since starting with iOS 7 receipt validation can be done local to the device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply  but I use my own web service to check the device so I done a validate on my web service thats why but my question will apple refuse my version if I dont use it?

Answer (score 0):

It's optional. Because from IOS7 , in app purchase is more safety. You can use validate or not. All accepted.
If you have any problem with validate receipt from client or server, I can help you. I have done validation receipt yesterday. :)