# When is appropriate to use Auto-Renewable Subscriptions - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

I am developing he application which delivers audio clips as channel basis media over http streaming.

I am planing to use **Auto-Renewable Subscriptions** in the app and they are renewing on monhly basis as we are updating the contents(Audio clips) of the channel frequently.

I was going through the Apple policy for auto renwing subscription which is,

**Definition**

Auto-renewable subscriptions allow users to purchase dynamic content, such as magazine subscriptions, for a set duration of time. Subscriptions renew automatically unless the user opts out of the renewal. If the content you want offer doesn’t fit what’s outlined in the App Review Guidelines, consider offering the content through a non-renewing subscription.
Auto-renewable subscriptions can include an incentive to customers who share their contact information with you.

**Review Guideline**

11.15. Apps may only use auto-renewing subscriptions for periodicals (newspapers, magazines), business Apps (enterprise, productivity, professional creative, cloud storage), and media Apps (video, audio, voice), or the App will be rejected

Its very confusing which method to use in my app (Auto-Renewing or Non-Renewing)
hense there are different types of thoughts/information shared on the internet.

So, my question is which method is appropriate to my app?

Can my product will get approval or not if I stick to use Auto-Renewable Subscriptions?

Further, if theres any complete tutorial/sample app for auto-renewable subscriptions please share with me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Auto-Renewable Subscriptions if you are going to change the content on certain time period basis.

But if this thing is going to be stopped in future then this way will not work for you. Any time Apple reject your application if he get complaints from any user.

To avoid this I will suggest to go with the Non-Renewing Subscription in that you are the one who is going to manage everything by your own. Apple will only provide facility to do transaction only. Rest of the things like management of time period will be on your hands only. In this case your application will not be rejected by Apple anytime in future as well.

Refer this [link](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit) for sample code which manages everything..

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes, the contents will be changed on certain time period basis. I am also, thinking of using auto-renewable subscriptions since the client prefer more towards it. Please share if there's any good tutorial, I couldn't found a latest one. Most of them are quite complex

Comment: I just edited my answer with the link to code.. In that everything was there & easy to use..

Comment: If that is helpful then accept the answer/upvote it.