# How to maped Autorenewal subscription with logedin user

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

In my application I have implemented auto renewal subscription that is working fine but how to map subscription with logedin user ??
As my application allows user's to login with there mobile number and subscribe with packs like 1 month, 3 month etc.. for streaming.

so my question is how my server & application know that user is belongs to that subscription so that if user login into different device e.g iOS or Android then user can access the contents to steam ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Store your subscription data into the server. When user logged in compare their email ID and check whether it is paid user for not. According to this condition you can rectify your users.

If you won't store the subscription data then its getting hard to you know who paid for the app.

If your app is **auto renewal**  (as you said), then you have restore. But it never work for the `cross-plateform`.

So I suggest you to store data in server DB through API and check the user when he logs in.

Hope it clears to you.

Comment: thanks for your answer but in case of renewal and cancellation how could application know about subscription ??

Comment: and what data I need to store ?? as i am login with mobile number and purchasing packs with any apple id then it is return receipt data

Comment: @AbhishekGupta your first answer is avable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944917/auto-renewable-subscription-for-in-app-purchase)

Comment: @AbhishekGupta For second question, you need to store each and every thing that you required to validate the user either user is paid or not. For example, you need phone number to check the user. You need subscription type to know upto when user is valid (user late date) so that they will use the app according to it. and many more things that you required to show .